# Confirm / Cancel SweetAlert are getting both confirmed

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Whether you click on "`Confirm`" or "`Cancel`", they perform both the function "`isConfirm`" and the "`Cancel`" does not close the alert as it should have done it. Basically, it seems to be closing and swallowing the SweetAlert triggered in the confirmation function. Does anyone have already seen this problem before?

```js
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
}, function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert@1.1.3/dist/sweetalert.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert@1.1.3/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly? When clicking on cancel or delete it seems to perform the correct functions? What do you mean by `basically, it seems to be closing and swallowing the SweetAlert triggered in the confirmation function.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tschallacka Yes, it's running fine with *sweetalert* but doesn't work for *sweetalert2*

Here is the solution with the correct syntax that works  for *sweetalert2*:

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
}).then(result => {
        if (result.value) {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        }
        else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
        }
    });
```

Hope it'll help future readers!